# Django and JavaScript: filtering not working paused on exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am trying to filter a table by the room name of the records which are in each row.  My table rows look like this:

```
 <tr data-room="{{ record.room.room_name|lower|field_name_format}}">
```

So, when the user checks kitchen, rows related to kitchen shows up in the table and not rows related to other rooms.

And this is the code in the header of my HTML:

```
{% for room in user_related_rooms %}
    document.querySelector('#{{room.room_name|lower|field_name_format}}').addEventListener('change',function (evt) {
    updateTableView("{{room.room_name|lower|field_name_format}}", evt.target.checked);
  });
{% endfor %}


function updateTableView(room_name, bVisible) {
    var dataSelectorVal = "";
    switch (room_name) 
    {
        {% for room in user_related_rooms %}
            case "{{room.room_name|lower|field_name_format}}":
            dataSelectorVal = ".site-table tbody tr[data-room='{{room.room_name|lower|field_name_format}}']";
            break;

          {% endfor %}
    }
    $(".site-table tbody tr").has(dataSelectorVal).css('display', bVisible ? "" : "none");
}
```

Here is the code for the filter:

```
 <!-- Filters -->
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <h1>Filters</h1>
        <form>
            <span> by room:</span>
            <div  class="side-filter-list">
                <ul>
                {% for room in user_related_rooms %}
                    <li class="flex-field">

                        <input type="checkbox" id="cb_{{room.room_name|lower|field_name_format}}" />
                        <label for="{{room.room_name}}">{{room.room_name}}</label>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The browser pauses on the exception. I get error on this line, living_room being the first room in the loop (i.e. the first iteration of the loop):

```
document.querySelector( '#cb_living_room' ).addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
```

It seems the above line returns null whereas when I comment out the code and use the console to look for it, it finds it without complaining:

```
document.querySelector( '#cb_living_room')
```

Console gives me the output:

```
<input id="cb_living_room" type="checkbox">
```

What am I doing wrong? What is going on?

Comment: It seems to me that you forgot to prepend a `'cb_'` in the following part of the code `document.querySelector('#{{room.room_name|lower|field_name_format}}').addEventListener(...`

Comment: Note that there is an asymmetry between this part of the code `id="cb_{{room.room_name|lower|field_name_format}}"` and this part `querySelector('#{{room.room_name|lower|field_name_format}}')`.

Comment: Thank you @ivissani.  I did fix that before pasting the second half of the code, but forgot to correct it in the first half.  That is why I get the error message document.querySelector( '#cb_living_room' ).addEventListener('change', function (evt)   in the first iteration of the loop.  In any event, the problem persists.  Any other idea?

Comment: Could you please paste te complete `<script></script>` tag where your JS is? Chances are that the script is running  before the browser finishes constructing the DOM therefore not finding the elements...